# Migrating from Apache to NGINX - config change

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, apache2

I am tring to migrate a legacy website from Apache to Nginx, but I can't rewrite the htaccess file to nginx config.

Current htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) $1.php?rewrite=$2 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried this nginx config (already tried a lot of modification but nothing is worked):

```
    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ $uri?rewrite=$args; # Not working
    try_files $uri $uri.php $uri?rewrite=index.php; # not working
    #try_files = $document_uri.php?rewrite=$args; #  not working
    fastcgi_pass localhost:8003;
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those "work" because the regex you specified in your `location` isn't the same as the regex you specified in Apache's .htaccess, and you aren't trying to use matches from it in `try_files`.

For the .htaccess you have posted, something like this should be more appropriate:

```
location ~ ^(.*)/(.*) {
    try_files $uri $1.php?rewrite=$2&$args =404;
}
```

This has the following effect: First try a static file, then a matching PHP script, otherwise return a 404.

Note that you don't `fastcgi_pass` here, but in another `location` specifically for handling PHP files.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    #...fastcgi config
}
```

---

When possible, you should consider refactoring the app to use a proper front controller. This will also reduce the complexity of your nginx configuration.